# Extract everything within brackets

Tags: php

I have a string of HTML with tags inside saved in the database e.g:

```
<p>Hello {$name}, welcome to {$shop_name}....</p>
```

I want to replace all of the tags with real data, now at the moment I loop through all available data and replace if it exists.

```
foreach($data as $key => $data){
    $content = str_replace('{$'.$key.'}', $data, $content);
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this without looping through all of the `$data`? This is now growing to over 5000 rows.

I mean is it possible to extract all variables {$name}/{$shop_name} then do a replace on only the found?

Comment: Why not use a off-the-shelf templating system?

Comment: Yes I have based the syntax from Smarty, although I dont want a massive template system, just some replace of vars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a single `str_replace` call.

```
$find = array();
$replace = array();
foreach($data as $key => $data) {
    $find[] = "\{$" . $key . "}";
    $replace[] = $data;
}
$content = str_replace($find, $replace, $content);
```

Unless there is a real performance issue, I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: Perfect, I cant believe I never knew it could accept arrays. Note the syntax error from using { inside "

Comment: Ah, just escape it. If that doesn't work, jump out the window while cursing PHP programmers.

Comment: @JohnMagnolia You can always look these kinds of things up yourself in the PHP manual: php.net/functionname (e.g. http://php.net/str_replace)

Answer (score 1):

`str_replace` accepts arrays, you can build the array with `array_keys`, `array_values` and user `array_map` to add the `{$}`

```
$content = str_replace(
               array_map(function($e) { return '{$' . $e . '}';}, array_keys($data)),
               array_values($data),
               $content);
```

Comment: Doesn't account for the `{$..}` template part, you need to build your match array first.

Comment: Good point, but that can be done with `array_map` which is in my opinion more elegant than building yourself. Added to answer.

Comment: thanks @dtech very cool how you can do all of this on 1 line. Although I found the other solution more readable for my basic level for now

Answer (score 0):

Can just do

```
$content = preg_replace('/\{$(\w+)\}/e', '$data[\'$1\']', $content);
```

Comment: This not entirely equivalent. It will also try to replace `{$doesntexist}`. Also regular expression is likely much slower.

Comment: And `/e` is deprecated and soon to be removed.